# How can I find the price of house and the garden?

Tags: arithmetic

A house and a garden were bought for 1000$, the cost of the house was 5 times that of garden.Find the price given for each.
(Actually I don't have any guidance book to solve this type of questions I have got a whole exercise of this type of questions without any example solution so please help me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing two equations in two variables, and then solving them together. Perhaps let $h$ stand for the cost of the house, and $g$ for the cost of the garden. Since they were bought together for \$1000, this gives us

$$g + h = 1000$$

Likewise, the second piece of information given is that the house costs $5$ times as much as the garden, so $h = 5g$.

Now what happens when you substitute the second equation into the first? Can you use that to find one of the variables, and then the second?

Comment: I could only pull it off to 6g=1000

Comment: If $6g = 1000$, then do you know how to solve for $g$?

Comment: I got g=1000/6
      
g=166.66666666666666666666666667

Comment: Try leaving it as a fraction; it's perfectly fine that way.

Comment: Ok solving the following equation-:G + h=1000 I got 1000=1000

Comment: Yeah I think I got the solution-:166.666666666666666666666667*5 gives 833.33333333333333333333333333333333

Comment: Thanks you very much T.Bongers